# MVC3 RC app deployed on IIS 6 giving "403 forbidden" error

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis-6, asp.net-mvc-3

I've deployed a very simple MVC3 RC app to an IIS 6 + Windows 2003 server. I'm just getting a "403 forbidden" error when trying to accesss the root. Right now the app is only one page, so there are no others to try out.

I noticed there is no longer a default.aspx in the root to handle default requests, could this maybe be the problem? Or is there some special config needed for IIS 6?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends. If you are using extensionless routes then yes there's a [special config](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/11/26/asp.net-mvc-on-iis-6-walkthrough.aspx).

Comment: I turned on wildcard mapping for now. bleh ;)

Comment: I found wildcard mapping solved the problem - was using ASP.Net 4 and MVC3 on IIS6/Windows 2003 and in spite of the "should just work" idea introduced with MVC3 it didn't for me.

Comment: This works particularly if you are getting 403 errors. If you apply this step and are getting 404 errors, try the following : http://twentyeighttwelve.com/iis-6-asp-net-mvc3-page-cannot-be-found-404-errors/

Answer (score 4):

I've just deployed an  MVC3 RC app on IIS6.0+win2003 server recently,

To get the route works correct ,all your should do is to intall .net framework4.0.
see this blog post from Haacked:
http://haacked.com/archive/2010/12/22/asp-net-mvc-3-extensionless-urls-on-iis-6.aspx

Comment: I'm not able to test this, but it does look like this might be the solution.

Comment: Actually in my specific case, I already had disabled extensionless urls on my server due to other incompatibilities. fun ;/

Answer (score 0):

Must read: http://haacked.com/archive/2010/12/22/asp-net-mvc-3-extensionless-urls-on-iis-6.aspx

Also, I installed Webmatrix via Web Platform Installer just to make sure that I had all that I needed.  Went through 2 reboots and voila~

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with Windows Server 2003 IIS6 running a MVC4 app for the first time - in the end a .NET 4 repair (I downloaded the dotNetFx40_Full_x86_x64.exe file from Microsoft and executed it) did the trick!

Recently I again had the same problem on a rebuilt server and this time I had forgotten to check **Web Service Extensions** (bottom "folder" in IIS6) and found that ASP.NET v4 was Prohibited. I changed it to allowed, restarted IIS Admin Service from Services and it started working.