# MVC3 iis6 app giving 404s and 403s

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, iis-6

A currently running app we have has started giving 404s and 403s. We have followed everything in this link to no avail. I am thinking that some security settings have been changed but I am not sure what settings or what user I need to check. Our production version of this website is currently running and I am afraid if I restart the server or services then it too will stop working.

[[MVC3 RC app deployed on IIS 6 giving "403 forbidden" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4186695/mvc3-rc-app-deployed-on-iis-6-giving-403-forbidden-error][1])

Comment: On IIS 6, 404 and 403 errors typically mean that you have either a) lost your wildcard mapping for running all request through the .NET pipeline or b) lost your mapping for the custom extension (example, .mvc) that you are applying to your routes.  Review Phil Haack's post here (http://haacked.com/archive/2008/11/26/asp.net-mvc-on-iis-6-walkthrough.aspx/) and ensure your server is configured correctly.

Comment: I have done that. As I said the site was running just fine. I have triple checked the wildcard mapping. When I just navigated to it from the IIS server I get the following error:  [FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Http, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.]
   TPGEnterprise.TpgInternalSite.MvcApplication.Application_Start()

Comment: I have figured this out. In the project I had to set 'Copy Local' to True for several references. Some how these had been reset to false.

Answer (score 0):

I have figured this out. In the project I had to set 'Copy Local' to True for several references. Some how these had been reset to false. System.Web.Http, System.Net.http.Formatting, System.Web.Http.Webhost